# What is the reason why protons and electrons do not collide?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, atoms, electromagnetic-radiation, protons

can someone give me an intuitive picture of why electrons don't collide with protons?

I know that electrons move in a sort of cloud, which is our 'orbital', and that they mainly behave like electromagnetic wave because of their very tiny mass. However, how comes they don't collide with the protons? I seriously didn't find a good explanation of these neither by professors I talked to nor by books, so a thousand points from me if you are able to get me into this.

Keep in mind that I am not looking for values, equations, or quantitative explanation of this, for that I have read enough, but for a picture. Think about the subatomic particles as you see them in your mind and describe their relationship.

Comment: @bon Thank you sir, I appreciate such a nice welcoming!

Comment: They kinda do collide, only they don't seem to care much.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Ok so far it matches my picture, since the probabilistic cloud of the lowest principal quantum number would cover the area of the nucleus as well, but since I am used to think about the acid and base behavior within molecules, I can't understand what is the barrier between electrons and protons..

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15727/how-does-the-vacuum-in-atoms-persist

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35437/why-dont-electrons-just-crash-into-the-nuclueus

Comment: @Mithoron before giving the -1 you should notice that all the answers to those question don't satisfy my question of an intuitive picture of the subatomic particles, which is why I asked on Physics S.E. as well about this, and there as well I didn't get an answer that can lead me to picture this... http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257180/atom-particles-relationships

Comment: "Collide" is the wrong word: it implies some kind of bouncing solid spheres, which are just not there. There is nothing to collide with. An electron does not just sometimes behave like a wave - it **is** a wave. Imagine a sea wave running against a lone rock. It will just run around the rock and continue on its way. Sure, once in a great while a wave would bring the rock down. Well, an electron has the chance to react with proton by means of K-capture.

Comment: @IvanNeretin this answer is worth the 1000 points. It is a very good picture that perfectly describes it! Indeed the more the rocks and the seawaves the more the power of them on each other, and the chance to get one of the rocks to fall within a wave (forming a neutron), which explains why K-Capture usually happens in bigger atoms. Thank you sir, I would add your answer in a book! If you write it down here I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do collide.  But it's not like cars crashing and smashing each other up on the highway.  Their quantum mechanical wavefunctions overlap and the electrons do in face settle in with wavefunctions that are centered on the nucleus.  But the low mass of the electrons, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle (which has its greatest effect on low-mass particles), and the Pauli exclusion principle (electrons can't all pile up in the most stable quantum state)  cause the electron wavefunctions to get diffused out around the nucleus.  Instead of getting smashed up, the electrons basically surround snd embed the atomic nucleus.

Comment: This is a good answer. Pretty similar to the one by @Ivan Neretin in the comments, even though his answer was even more accurate onto giving an example. Thank you both guys!

Comment: My comment is **not** more accurate (which, BTW, is why I'd rather not turn it into an answer). If anything, it is more _picturesque_, but remember: the whole thing about sea waves and rocks is but a metaphor, and those are not intended to draw practical conclusions.

Comment: You are welcome.  I woll make sure to +1 Ivan's comment.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin yes of course I know that, but it's a good metaphore which gives the idea of that.